# How to update package in Fedora 24 when repo newest version is too old?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf, software-updates

I am running a fresh install of Fedora 24, and at boot time and other times I get a selinux alert: its [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1341753).

The fix is, to update package selinux-policy from installed version 3.13.1-191.**8**.fc24 to 3.13.1-191.**9**.fc24

However, using dnf, the newest version available in the repos is release 191.8.  I could probably google up the newer file and drop it in the correct place in the system, but is that really the best way to do this?  The most recent comment in the bug report says that release 9 fixed their issue 3 days ago...how did they get that update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can go to [Koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/) build system and grab the latest build:

- http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=32

But be careful because there are other derived packages from `selinux-policy` so you should download them as well if they are installed on your system.

Use `dnf` to update, for example:

```
$ sudo dnf update selinux-policy-3.13.1-191.10.fc24.noarch.rpm selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-191.10.fc24.noarch.rpm ...
```

Comment: Can you tell me, if I grab the packages from Koji and install, will dnf automatically recognize when the repos have the next version, 191.11 for example, and update the packages, or will I have to go back in a few weeks and pull the manually installed pkgs and re-install the repo pkgs?  When I try your suggested command it throws an error "none of the providers can be installed, try --allowerasing"

Comment: Yes, they will be updated because they will have higher versions. Koji is the system where Fedora packages are built. About the error, check all the selinux packages that are installed on your machine and download them all from Koji, then install those packages as I showed above.